# incompatible types in Equal Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(trip_id:chararray) right hand side:chararray

Tags: apache-pig

I am unable to generate SUM(km) using trip_id from below code:

```
twa = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:54310/sImport_20170508100625/t_waypoint_actual.txt' USING  PigStorage('|') as
(id:int, trip_id:chararray, address_id:int, timestamp_utc:chararray, driver_id:int, ETA:chararray,event_id:int, imei_number:chararray, vehicle_imei_id:int,
km:double, avg_speed:double, duration:chararray, signal_strength:float, battery_strength:float, event_type:chararray);

twa_group = GROUP twa BY (id,trip_id,km);
twa_foreach = FOREACH twa_group GENERATE FLATTEN(group), twa.trip_id AS trip_id, (SUM(twa.km)) AS km;
twa_filter = FILTER twa_foreach BY (trip_id == '466');

DUMP twa_filter;
```

Error:

```
In alias twa_filter, incompatible types in Equal Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(trip_id:chararray)  right hand side:chararray
```

I tried several methods but no output. Can anyone suggest me the correct solution. Thanks in advance.

```
Input:
id,trip_id,km
1,466,1.4
2,466,2.3


 Expected Output:
    trip_id,km
     466,3.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select column from grouped data the result is always a bag, but as you are grouping by this column you can just select it from group key.

```
twa_foreach = FOREACH twa_group GENERATE group.id as id, groum.km as km, 
group.trip_id AS trip_id, (SUM(twa.km)) AS km;
twa_filter = FILTER twa_foreach BY (trip_id == '466');
```

In case you'll need to use column that's not in the key, you'll need to use `limit 1` + `flatten`.

okay, inspected your code a bit. Looks like you want to obtain sum of km for each `id, trip_id` pair. Assuming it
`cat testdata/7.csv`:

```
1|456|2.5|somedata1
2|466|2.7|somedata2
2|466|2.7|somedata2
4|456|2.8|somedata3
4|456|2.9|somedata4
4|456|2.9|somedata4
5|466|2.5|somedata5
5|466|2.5|somedata5
```

And the pig script

```
twa = LOAD 'testdata/7.csv' USING  PigStorage('|') as
(id:int, trip_id:chararray, km:double, event_type:chararray);

twa_group = GROUP twa BY (trip_id);
twa_foreach = FOREACH twa_group GENERATE group AS trip_id, (SUM(twa.km)) AS km;
twa_filter = FILTER twa_foreach BY (trip_id == '466');
DUMP twa_filter;
```

The result is

```
(466,10.4)
```

If this doesn't work for you - you are doing smth wrong. Also consider doing filtering *before* grouping as `group operation is really costly

Comment: no it is not working. If i am using twa_group = GROUP twa ALL;
twa_foreach = FOREACH twa_group GENERATE (SUM(twa.km)) AS km;
then some output is coming, but when i am adding filter clause twa_filter = FILTER twa_foreach BY (trip_id == '466');
It is saying: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias twa_filter. Backend error : java.io.IOException: Incorrect value for packet payload size: 67633156
what may be the reason??

Comment: ofc it's not working, in your original question you use `GROUP twa BY (id,trip_id,km);` not `group .. all`

Comment: I tried both queries but i am not getting exact output.

Comment: Thank you very much,whatever the output your getting it is some what correct, even i got that but my exact output is trip_id: 466, sum(km): 10.40 which is sum of (5.4+5.0) should be generated. Hope you got my point. For better understanding I have edited input and output.